# Wordpress custom hook to fetch plugin version (latest) after update it

Tags: wordpress, hook

im trying to get plugin name and plugin versions of plugins that has been recently updated and save it to a txt file.

Example in this txt file:

> **Jetpack** had version **3.9.2** now its **3.9.4**

Is there a way to make a custom hook that find the update process and retrieve the update number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try it with [upgrader_process_complete](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete).

```
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', function( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
    // inspect $options
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Sorry I was the idiot here.. It worked 90%, the last 10% i got stuck.. but now i know it works at least :D

Comment: Great :) Than you can check this answer "correct". Where you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at how to get it to look each update to get the version and name... it skips all updates until it comes to the last one.. then it show the info from the last one

Comment: My code: static function action_upgrader_process_complete( $upgrader, $options ) {
  if ( is_array( $options ) && $options['action'] === 'update' && $options['type'] === 'plugin' ) {
   $plugin     = $upgrader->skin->plugin_info;
   $processing = $upgrader->strings;
//   var_dump( $upgrader );

   if ( isset( $processing['no_package'] ) || isset( $processing['process_failed'] ) ) {
    echo __( 'Read the error log', 'iqq' );
   } 
   echo $plugin['Name'] . " - " . $plugin['Version'];
  }
 }